# How can I draw with mouse on html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have two problems: how can I draw rectangles with mouse o html canvas, and why isn't my timer showing up.
I have tried every code in here but nothing seems to work. Thank you!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas Resize</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <p id="timer"></p>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');


//TIMER
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');

var counter = 0;

function setup(){
    timer = createP('timer');
    setInterval(timeIt, 1);
}

function timeIt (){
    timer.html(counter);
    counter+=134;
}
```

Here's the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rita24/0vLwj3go/2/

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't taken a look at the console, there's an error message waiting for you.

Comment: `createP` is not defined, and you never call `setup`. You also probably mean 1000, not 1, for your interval, it’s in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

For the canvas part, you can just add the event listener to keep track on the mouseup, mousemove and mousedown event.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  drawing = true;
  lastPos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  drawing = false;
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
}, false);

// Get the position of the mouse relative to the canvas
function getMousePos(canvasDom, mouseEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left,
    y: mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

This will help you create the rectangle on canvas.

```
ctx.rect(mousePos.x,mousePos.y,lastPos.x-mousePos.x,lastPos.y-mousePos.y);
ctx.stroke();
```

You can check this out on how to work with mouse drawing on the canvas: http://bencentra.com/code/2014/12/05/html5-canvas-touch-events.html

For the timer part, you haven't called the setup() function and you are using jQuery html() function to setup the text inside the p element. Use .innerHTML to change the text inside the p element.

Here is the updated link for your JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0vLwj3go/7/

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

Elvis' answer is great, but since I had already started mine this morning, I'll post it anyway.

For one thing, you aren't calling setup() anywhere, so the timer never gets set and the timer `<p>` never gets any content.  Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bdoughty/700dmtzp/), which is very similar to Elvis', but shows the timer without scrolling, and includes an example of how to animate the drawing of rectangles.